# How do I create a side-by-side file diff importable as a *table* by Excel, Word, or Google Docs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, csv, text-formatting, diff

`diff -y file1 file2` creates output like this:

[image]

I want to take this output and convert it to a CSV format where

- the text at left is in one column,
- the < or | or >, if any, is in the second column, and
- the text at right is in the 3rd column.

The point of this is to be able to use common productivity software to discuss diffs with non technical users that I cannot expect to install pull review software.

I am not married to `diff` as the starting point to the solution if there are better options, but the outcome has to be a three column exportable file.

Comment: If you replace for example the "   <   " by ",<," and so on, this would become a CSV file.

Comment: @harrymc this wouldn't work for all the lines with no |, <, or >.  if you filter those out you wouldn't have much idea of where the insertion was.

Comment: You may use the long string of blanks, if no such exist inside the text.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works in Excel, but I've had good results in LibreOffice Calc using constant-width fields when importing the diff output. For example:

```
diff -yt file1.txt file2.txt > diffoutput.txt
```

The `-t` option is useful for dealing with tab characters. You can adjust the diff output line width with the `--width` diff parameter.